# How to convert an output of a matrix into a PNG image?

Tags: graphics, matrix

Using [**@m_goldberg's code**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98705/193) I have created a matrix with the following command:

```
MatrixForm[{{n, -1 + n, -2 + n, ⋯, 1}, {2 n, 2 n - 1, 
2 n - 2, ⋯, n + 1}, {3 n, 3 n - 1, 
3 n - 2, ⋯, 
2 n + 1},  {⋮, ⋮, ⋮, ⋱, ⋮}, {n^2, -1 + n^2, -2 + n^2,⋯, 
HoldForm[(n - 1) n + 1]}},   TableAlignments -> {Center, Center}] // TraditionalForm
```

If I save the output I get a small, low quality PNG picture.

So, is there a way to convert an output to a graph, or enlarge it? So that to get a better and larger picture of a matrix? I would appreciate any hint or suggestion.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative that produces a sharp image is

```
m = {{n, -1 + n, -2 + n, ⋯, 1}, 
     {2 n, 2 n - 1, 2 n - 2, ⋯, n + 1}, 
     {3 n, 3 n - 1, 3 n - 2, ⋯, 2 n + 1}, 
     {⋮, ⋮, ⋮, ⋱, ⋮},  
     {n^2, -1 + n^2, -2 + n^2, ⋯, HoldForm[(n - 1) n + 1]}};
Rasterize@Style[MatrixForm[m, TableAlignments -> {Center, Center}] // TraditionalForm), 30]
```

[image]

Then, right-click the image, choose "Save Graphic As...", and store the image in the desired format.

**Addendum**

In response to the OP's comment below, columns can be given different colors by

```
clr = {Red, Orange, Green, Blue, Magenta};
Rasterize@Style[MatrixForm[MapIndexed[Style[#1, clr[[Last@#2]]] &, m, {2}], 
    TableAlignments -> {Center, Center}] // TraditionalForm, 30]
```

[image]

Replace `Last` by `First` to give rows different colors instead.  Also, as noted by [george2079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079) in another comment below, the font can be set by replacing `30` by, for instance, `{FontFamily -> Times, 30}`.

Comment: annoying that `Style` changes the font isn't it.. fix with `{FontFamily -> Times, 30}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I would like to colour some columns different colours but so far I can only change the colour for the whole matrix. May I ask if there is a way to colour the columns different colours? Thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

```
Export["test.png", MatrixForm[ ..] // TraditionalForm, 
         ImageSize -> 500, ImageResolution -> 1000]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
ImageResize[
 Rasterize@(MatrixForm[{{n, -1 + n, -2 + n, ⋯, 1}, {2 n, 2 n - 1, 
     2 n - 2, ⋯, n + 1}, {3 n, 3 n - 1, 3 n - 2, ⋯, 
     2 n + 1},  {⋮, ⋮, ⋮, ⋱, ⋮}, {n^2, -1 + n^2, -2 + n^2,⋯, HoldForm[(n - 1) n + 1]}}, 
     TableAlignments -> {Center, Center}] // TraditionalForm), 500]
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the various approaches yielding rasterized images, you can use [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) to obtain a vector graphics:

```
yourTable = MatrixForm[{{n, -1 + n, -2 + n, ⋯, 1}, {2 n, 2 n - 1, 
2 n - 2, ⋯, n + 1}, {3 n, 3 n - 1, 
3 n - 2, ⋯, 
2 n + 1},  {⋮, ⋮, ⋮, ⋱, ⋮}, {n^2, -1 + n^2, -2 + n^2,⋯, 
HoldForm[(n - 1) n + 1]}},   TableAlignments -> {Center, Center}] // TraditionalForm;

<< "MaTeX`"
MaTeX[TeXForm[yourTable]]
Export["test.pdf",%]
```

[Here](https://filetea.me/n3wGI9OTqXCR7uaJO3bONolVQ) is the result of the above code.

Of course you can combine this with bbgodfrey's answer of using colored columns if you include the color package for latex:

```
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{color}"}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit bbgodfrey's code for having control of resolution and size:

```
m = {{n, -1 + n, -2 + n, ⋯, 1}, 
     {2 n, 2 n - 1, 2 n - 2, ⋯, n + 1}, 
     {3 n, 3 n - 1, 3 n - 2, ⋯, 2 n + 1}, 
     {⋮, ⋮, ⋮, ⋱, ⋮},  
     {n^2, -1 + n^2, -2 + n^2, ⋯, HoldForm[(n - 1) n + 1]}};

Rasterize[
 Style[MatrixForm[%, TableAlignments -> {Center, Center}] // 
   TraditionalForm], RasterSize -> 1000, ImageSize -> 500]
Export["filename.png", %];
```