# Is it possible to colour only one column of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, color

I was wondering if it's possible to colour a column or a row in a matrix.

For example is it possible to add colour for one of the rows/columns of the following matrixform code?

```
MatrixForm[{{n, -1 + n, -2 + n, ⋯, 1}, {2 n, 2 n - 1, 
 2 n - 2, ⋯, n + 1}, {3 n, 3 n - 1, 3 n - 2, ⋯, 
 2 n + 1},  {⋮, ⋮, ⋮, ⋱, ⋮}, {n^2, -1 + n^2, -2 + n^2,⋯, HoldForm[(n - 1) n + 1]}}]
```

I would appreciate any help or suggestion.

EDIT: For example what if we want to colour only one column in the following matrix?

```
Rasterize@
Style[MatrixForm[{{n, -1 + n, -2 + n, ⋯, 1}, {2 n, 2 n - 1, 
 2 n - 2, ⋯, n + 1}, {3 n, 3 n - 1, 3 n - 2, ⋯, 
 2 n + 1},  {⋮, ⋮, ⋮, ⋱, ⋮}, {n^2, -1 + n^2, -2 + n^2,⋯, HoldForm[(n - 1) n + 1]}}, 
TableAlignments -> {Center, Center}] // TraditionalForm, 
Background -> LightBlue, FontFamily -> Times, 30]
```

[image]

EDIT: Thanks to @Kuba, @E.Doroskevic and @Mr. Wizard I managed to get the following matrix:

```
Grid[Table[{{1, 2, 3, ⋯, 10}, {2, 3, 4, ⋯, 11}, {3, 4, 5, ⋯, 12}, 
   {⋮, ⋮, ⋮, ⋱, ⋮}, {10, 11, 12, ⋯, 20}}], Background ->{{LightBlue},None}, 
   ItemStyle -> {{Red, Blue, Green, Black}}, ItemSize -> {5, 5}]
```

[image]

Also how can I present the above as a matrix with parentheses or square brackets?

I have tried `\\MatrixForm` but it didn't work.

Comment: You can use `MapIndexed[]` to apply `Style[]` to any particular row, column, or entry.

Comment: @J.M. Could you kindly show me a simple example? Thank you.

Comment: Why not experiment? I already pointed out the functions you'll need to use; look up how they're used in the docs, and try things out. If you get stuck, edit your question to include what you tried with these, and we'll take it from there.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the help. The bit I don't understand is what **f** should be in `MapIndexed[f,Style[expr,options]]`.

Comment: Grid has `Background` option which quite wide documentation. Take a look there.

Comment: If you want to apply `Style[]` to a particular row/column/entry, then `Style[]` should appear somewhere in the first argument of `MapIndexed[]`. You might need to use a conditional like `If[]`, `Which[]`, or `Switch[]` as well.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31152/131

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks, but how one can colour only one column at a time? The difference with my problem and the example you reference is that the entries of the matrix are written explicitly and I don't know how to get to colour using `Background` a specific column of explicit entries.

Comment: Duplicates earlier [question and associated comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98746/1063).

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for the answer in the previous question. I have solved my problem. Could you advise what to do now for the current question? Should I delete it? Or wait for a modetator to close it?

Comment: Just leave it, since others have invested some time providing advice.  No harm done.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer:**
*Taken from documentation*

**Code:**

```
Grid[Table[x, {4}, {7}], Background -> {{Pink}, None}]
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Reference:**
[Grid](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html)

**P.S**
Most specifically look at the documentation provided for the associated option `Background`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I present the required output as a matrix with parentheses?

Comment: @johnny09 wrap the code above with `{ }`? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Not exactly. What I want is to create a matrix. So I need parentheses or square brackets to the left and right of the entries.

Comment: @johnny09 I would advise you to refer to the reference left above in my answer. However, based on my comprehension of what you are aiming to achieve, following (simplified) sample should suffice as a demonstration: {Grid[{{x, x, x}, {x, x, x}}, Background -> {{Pink}, None}]}

Comment: maybe `{Grid[Table[x, {4}, {7}], Background -> {{Pink}, None}]} // MatrixForm // Rasterize`?